# Entity Framework: custom primary key

Tags: .net, entity-framework, primary-key

How can I create a custom primary key with auto increment in Entity Framework?

Primary key format: [Month][Year][Index]

The [index] value will be reset for every month.

example:
This month: the primary key will start from 082013001, until 082013999
Then the next month: 092013001, until 092013999

If EF can't have a custom primary key, what is the best way for me to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing -- I think it will help if you  clarify this _"The [index] value will be reset for every month."_ a little bit.

Comment: Make your key a string and use a function to initialize it

Comment: @kirsteng can you provide more details? I also need to handle the scenario where multiple records being inserted at the same time.

Comment: how about making the primary key on 2  columns. The first could be MMYYYY and the second could be an identity

Comment: Are you _absolutely_ sure that these values will _never ever_ change?